# Java is eating up 300% of my CPU

Tags: macos, java

Can anyone help me find the cause behind java taking up 300+% of my CPU? I've shut down almost every app and am still having trouble trying to locate the cause.

[image]

Comment: Let's start by getting a better view. Knowing the parent process may help diagnose it. Doudble click on the java process and post the screen shot of the info window. Also...CrashPlan is a java application. I'm betting that's the culprit.

Comment: CrashPlan will keep running even if you Quit it! run this in Terminal to confirm "ps auxww | grep -i CrashPlanService"

Comment: I found this article how to get the crashplan and Java under control. http://www.chainsawonatireswing.com/2012/04/08/how-to-use-crashplan-but-keep-the-java-process-from-constantly-using-ridiculous-amounts-of-ram/

Comment: I also gave you answer how to reset the crashplan (which I would recommend) but the community found it premature and a wild guess, so I removed it for peace sake.

Comment: Thanks Buscar - I killed CrashPlan with: `sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.crashplan.engine.plist` and made sure it was dead with: `ps auxww | grep -i CrashPlanService` and it's no longer running, but when I try to kill java with: `killall -KILL java` Java just restarts and is still running over 100% CPU.

Comment: Ian C. here's a screenshot of the process ... http://shot.taylor.kiwi.nz/image/2n382V0T0N0g

Answer (score 4):

For me it was Cassandra using java. It took me a couple of hours to figure this out. I used:

**ps -A |grep java**

... And there were a huge list with processes using java. I saw "Cassandra" so many times that I decided to stop that process with brew. Once you stop the process that is using java, your CPU will work fine.

**brew services stop cassandra**

Maybe you installed Java lately to use some other program? It might be that program causing this error.

Answer (score 3):

Ian C. put me on the right track. I checked out the items that were running in Java by using the Open Files & Ports tab on the process.

This lead me to ElasticSearch running on my machine. So I removed that and now it looks to be running without overheating again. Yay!